# Decode JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm new to Json and haven't touched PHP for some time. I am using a json weather api to display current weather conditions on a web page. I have now decide to add a forecast as well. The forecast is supplied in the same jason file but in a slightly different format and i can not get my PHP code to extract it. I think it is because the forecast is an array where the current conditions is not, but still no Joy.

A snippet from the json file:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "geolookup": 1
  ,
  "conditions": 1
  ,
  "forecast": 1
  }
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"Clifton, Bristol, ",
        "city":"Clifton, Bristol",
        "state":"",
        "country":"UNITED KINGDOM",
        "country_iso3166":"GB",
        "latitude":"51.464230",
        "longitude":"-2.616240",
        "elevation":"230 ft"
        },
        "estimated": {
        },
        "station_id":"IBRISTOL22",
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on June 6, 8:34 AM BST",
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Fri, 06 Jun 2014 08:34:16 +0100",
        "observation_epoch":"1402040056",
        "local_time_rfc822":"Fri, 06 Jun 2014 08:38:21 +0100",
    "feelslike_string":"56.7 F (13.7 C)",
    "feelslike_f":"56.7",
    "feelslike_c":"13.7",
    "visibility_mi":"N/A",
    "visibility_km":"N/A",
    "solarradiation":"246",
    "UV":"1.1","precip_1hr_string":"0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
    "precip_1hr_in":"0.00",
    "precip_1hr_metric":" 0",
    "precip_today_string":"0.00 in (0 mm)",
    "precip_today_in":"0.00",
    "precip_today_metric":"0",
    "icon":"clear",
    "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
    "forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/03726.html",
    "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=IBRISTOL22",
    "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=51.464230,-2.616240"
}
    ,
"forecast":{
    "txt_forecast": {
    "date":"7:36 AM BST",
    "forecastday": [
    {
    "period":0,
    "icon":"partlycloudy",
    "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
    "title":"Friday",
    "fcttext":"Partly to mostly cloudy. High 74F. Winds ESE at 10 to 20 mph.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Mostly cloudy skies early, then partly cloudy this afternoon. High 23C. Winds ESE at 15 to 30 kph.",
    "pop":"10"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":1,
    "icon":"nt_rain",
    "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_rain.gif",
    "title":"Friday Night",
    "fcttext":"Partly cloudy skies early then becoming cloudy with occasional rain and a rumble or two of thunder late. Low around 60F. Winds ESE at 10 to 15 mph. Chance of rain 90%.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy skies this evening will give way to periods of rain and possibly a thunderstorm overnight. Low 15C. Winds ESE at 15 to 25 kph. Chance of rain 90%.",
    "pop":"90"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":2,
    "icon":"rain",
    "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif",
    "title":"Saturday",
    "fcttext":"Becoming partly cloudy after some morning rain. High around 70F. Winds SSW at 10 to 20 mph. Chance of rain 90%. Rainfall around a quarter of an inch.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Rain early. A mix of sun and clouds in the afternoon. High 21C. Winds SSW at 15 to 25 kph. Chance of rain 90%. Rainfall around 6mm.",
    "pop":"90"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":3,........
```

I have managed to extract the conditions part with the following code.

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/XXXXXAPI-CodeXXXXX/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/pws:ibristol22.json");
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
  $feelslike = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'feelslike_c'};

  echo "<strong>Feels Like:</strong> ${feelslike} <br>";
```

What PHP code would I need to say extract 'fcttext_metric' from period '0' of 'forecast' -> 'forecastday'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `$parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday`:

```
foreach ($parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday as $forecastday)
{
    if ($forecastday->period == 0)
    {
        echo('fcttext_metric=' . $forecastday->fcttext_metric);
        // ...(do something else)...
    }
}
```

or, if there's always the same order of output data, simplier:

```
echo('fcttext_metric=' . $parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday[0]->fcttext_metric);
```

assuming that data with `period: 0` is always at the first element of `forecastday`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but i can not get either of these solutions working. i have tried this:

    foreach ($parsed_json->forecast->forecastday as $forecastday)
    {
    echo "1";    
    }

and no 1s are displayed.